# Local Symfony site hosted in container is unreachable

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose, containerd, rancher-desktop

I have the following setup for local development:

- Symfony website in a Docker container
- Using the `symfony serve` command in the container to serve the website
- Port mapping `"8083:8000"` specified in the docker-compose.yaml
- Using `containerd` container runtime with `nerdctl compose up` to run the Docker containers. These are on macOS Ventura using Rancher Desktop.

#### Expected behavior

Going to https://127.0.0.1:8083 or https://localhost:8083 in a browser while the Symfony site is being served in its container should serve the website hosted on the container's port 8000.

#### Actual behavior

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED from the browser -- the website refuses to connect.

---

### Details

#### `docker-compose.yaml` (relevant parts):

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    container_name: nudgeforce-api
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8083:8000"
    command: php
    volumes:
      - .:/var/task
```

#### Dockerfile

```docker
FROM bref/php-82-fpm
RUN yum install -y git gzip zip unzip python3 tar
COPY --from=composer:2.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
WORKDIR /var/task
# Symfony server
RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony \
    && symfony server:ca:install
```

#### `symfony serve` output

[image]

Comment: What happens if you try to access your site on http instead of https?

Comment: In your Dockerfile, did you expose port 8083?